# Meaning of the same side up

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of **the same side up** in the following sentence.

> If two maps of the same plane region are superimposed, **the same side up**, on a plane then by our theorems there will be one and only one point whose representations in the maps will coincide.

How is **up** used in this sentence? Is it adjective or adverb or prepositions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider two maps, or any other objects that have two sides. We may arbitrarily name the sides 1 and 2, A and B, front and back, top and bottom, etc. If two or more such objects are placed so that the same side of each is facing up, then they are 'the same side up'.

Comment: But that doesn't directly answer the question. The entire phrase is acting adverbially, since it's describing *how* they are superimposed.